# Service not available, closing transmission channel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, smtp

I am using below code in web.config but i got the below error.
      Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was:Connect to SMTP server 173.194.70.109 (173.194.70.109:587), connect error 10060.

```
<system.net>

    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
    <proxy proxyaddress="100.0.0.0" usesystemdefault="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>

    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="abc@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" 
        password="abc" userName="abc@gmail.com" />
       </smtp>
     </mailSettings>

</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to indicate that error 10060 results from connecting to the internet via a service that prohibits you from using any SMTP server other than their own.

See also this page for a list of required server names that may apply:

Comment: tanks for reply can you explain in detail?

Comment: Just try searching web. A lot of results are there.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall and antivirus. Try to disable both or either of them and try,I got the same error and got it sorted by disabling avast.